Do experimental projects harm my theoretical profile?
Half a year ago I finished my undergraduate degree in Physics and I am currently waiting for the results of admission to the postgraduate program. My goal is to start a master's degree either this year or the following year, but specifically in Theoretical Physics.
Although I am currently working on some articles that are the result of my thesis on gravitation, I also collaborate with a professor dedicated to experimental physics. We are finishing a project that I started in the third semester as part of an experimental physics course, in which I developed a theoretical model. However, I am uncertain about this work. My main concern is that, when applying to Theoretical Physics programs, this project will not be relevant or useful for my profile, since the models and results obtained do not have a particularly novel impact, and it is unlikely that the derived articles will be even slightly cited.
Furthermore, although the plan is to continue with this project and generate more publications, I doubt that they will contribute significantly to my development in the area of ​​Theoretical Physics. A professor told me that, given my interest in a theoretical graduate program, this type of experimental work would probably be ignored by admissions committees.
My question is: is it worth continuing to spend time on these types of experimental projects? To what extent could they harm my aspirations to specialize exclusively in Theoretical Physics? Although I know that I could abandon the project, I feel committed, since it was born as a personal idea and was an individual work during that third semester course.

You might be interested: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/126616/do-universities-favor-experimentalists-over-theoreticians

Context: I am a former theoretical physics postdoc, and have evaluated applications for a theory PhD program.
As a masters student, you are likely to be perceived as more or less a "baby" from a research point of view. So, while it is true that projects related to your field of interest (ie, your thesis on gravitational theory) are going to be weighted the most strongly in your application, I think it's generally also true that any research you completed will be considered positively. If you are going into phenomenology (ie, applying theory to come up with observational predictions), and if your experimental project is related to observations that are connected to the type of phenomenology you are interested in, then you could make a case that the experimental project gives you a deeper insight into observations. But, even if that is not the case, I would expect that the fact you have demonstrated the ability to do research will be considered a plus.
It is probably true that if you could go back and time, and spend the time you had spent on the experimental project on additional theoretical research, that would help you more. But, that is not an option. And, spending your life optimizing one outcome (like getting into grad school for theory) isn't always the best approach -- spending time to explore another interest gives you a unique perspective which may help you understand things that others don't and if nothing else can give you personal satisfaction.
Another thing to keep in mind is that, assuming you did a good job on the experimental project and are on good relationship with your supervisor, you will get a good letter of recommendation from this person. Having letters from multiple people who can speak positively about your research skills when going into a PhD program will be a positive.
Finally, I want to caveat my answer by adding that different admissions committees will weigh things differently, so your best bet is ultimately just to apply as broadly as you can given your ability to cover application fees and see what happens. My answer is what I would expect an "average" admissions committee member to think.
All of the above is specifically about the question about applying to a PhD program given your research history. However, another aspect of this question is, should you continue working on the experimental side? Here, my answer would change. While you are currently being evaluated on your potential to succeed in a PhD program, as you progress through your PhD and beyond you will increasingly be judged on what you have accomplished. Then, it is important to be the "best" in some specific topic, so people think of you as the expert in that area. This is part of how you build a reputation in your field. It is extremely hard to spread yourself across multiple technical areas and still be "the best." It is a sad fact of life, but there are only so many hours in a day, and you are competing with people who will spend those hours on one area, so splitting yourself will only end up meaning that you are working less on a given area than others in your cohort. So, moving forward, if you know you want to do theory, it will be much more beneficial to you in the long term to give up the experimental work and focus on theory, and indeed to find a niche within theory where you can make strong and consistent contributions.

Your paper sounds relevant and valuable
For application to a masters program it is likely that the expected level of research accomplishment is low.  You are not expected to already by a published specialist in your desired field when coming into a masters program.  Any research publications you have produced are likely to be looked on favourably and will demonstrate research capability.  Even if you were to publish a paper on sixteenth-century French poetry, it would still demonstrate that you have some experience in the craft of undertaking research, performing a literature review, writing a clear and logical paper suitable for academic publication, and then dealing with the refereeing/revisions/proofing process in the publication system.
Publishing a paper in experimental physics is directly relevant to your desired field.  Any good theory in theoretical physics will ultimately need to be testable by experiment and so having experience designing, executing and reporting physics experiments is surely valueable even in that field.  Even if your experiment is not particularly novel, your paper can still demonstrate competence in executing and reporting the experiment, and tying the results back to your theoretical model in a sensible way.  That is extremely valuable for an incoming masters student.  If it is true that the theoretical physics academics would see an experimental physics paper like this as having no value for an incoming student (which I highly doubt) then I think they're twits.  (Richard Feynman would turn in his grave.)
